# how to install the Parallel::ForkManager module?

Tags: perl

Can't locate `Parallel/ForkManager.pm` in `@INC` (you may need to install the `Parallel::ForkManager` module) (`@INC` contains: `C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib`,  `C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib`, `C:/Strawberry/perl/lib`)

Comment: Follow this -https://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html

Answer (score 0):

Strawberry Perl comes with the cpan package

```
cpan -i Parallel::ForkManager
```

should work